# Use newer Java version than 17 with Graal native image

Tags: android, javafx, graalvm, gluon

I'm making a Sokoban app with JavaFx and Gluon's tools (see https://github.com/hallvard/halban), and currently targeting Android. I would like to use Java 19, 20 or 21, but it seems Java 17 is the most recent Java version that can be used with Graal native image? For MacOS I am able to use Java 19 and GraalVM 22.3.r19-grl, but when using Github actions for building the Android version, 22.1.0.1-Final seems to be used (by the setup-graalvm action).

I've looked for more recent releases at https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases, but 22.1.0.1-Final is the newest I found.

Can I make setup-graalvm use a newer GraalVM version?
I no, do you plan to update to a newer one, preferably one supporting Java 21?

Comment: I am also waiting for newer version of stable gluon but if you want you can try *22-ea+16* from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)